# In App Store Connect, app preview poster frame not saving

Tags: app-store-connect, app-preview

I've added some video app previews for my app on App Store Connect and when I set the video poster frame, it never saves the image that I want, it always reverts back to the one that Apple defaults to initially. Does anyone know a work around?

UPDATE: I did get in contact with App Store Connect and they told me it's a recent bug that they're actively working on fixing. I'm going to touch base with them early next week.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seems to be happening to me too.

Comment: @whidev Nah I just gave up on it sadly. Ridiculous that they never bothered to fix it.

Comment: Issue is still happening. Have to fiddle with the poster frame multiple times to get it to work.

Comment: @SamBing Yeah I just had more issues with it and contacted support again and they didn't care. Also had a major bug where my screenshots got erased when I created a new version after I tried to implement the screenshots from a product page optimization and they were just like hrmph, not our problem.

Comment: Recently working on for 2 years.... it drives me crazy big companies are like this... get it right

Answer (score 1):

Issue is still happening. But if you want to be able to upload without problems try this:

1. Upload the screenshots of one complete language
2. Don't touch anything for 2-4 min once pictures are uploaded.
3. Then you can refresh the webpage and check if the screenshots are well uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you need to pause on the image that you want to make the poster screenshot for at least .5 seconds in your app preview. Then when you set it to the poster, wait 10 minutes for it to update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will appreciate my answer, because I come with a solution to your problems :)

After several tests, we already know that either it is a Bug, or that being so optimized everything for loading images, files, videos, etc... You can always lose the exact frame we are looking for. So let's not waste time in judging this, because if to this day has not yet been solved by apple, it is because the effort to improve or sacrifice, is greater than the result. That said? the solution is :

Since we know that it does not detect well the exact Frame that we want to show the fragment of the video, by thousands of seconds. The advice is to go to the end of the video when we are editing it and add the presentation image that we want to show, at the end of the video. But with a duration of 1 second. That is to say, the Frame that we want to show as an image must be at the end of the video from Minute 0:29 to 0:30 (The duration of this image must be 1 second at the end of the video). This way, when we go to the dashboard and we want to choose the exact Frame, we will simply go to the end of the video with the help of the buttons that apple shows us below the video ( Forward the video ) and we go to the last frame. We set the Frame and that's it. Problem solved. I hope it helps you all and no longer lose more time trying to square images in a thousand different ways as I and many have happened to us. Good luck in the development. See you.